# Odd derivatives of a function $f$ satisfying $f(1/z)=-f(z)$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Suppose $f$ is a function in $z$ such that for all $z$, $$f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)=-f(z).$$ (Examples are $\frac{1-z}{1+z}$ and $\log z$.) It turns out that for odd $k$, $f^{(k)}(1)$ is independent of $f^{(j)}(1)$ for all $j<k$, whereas for even $k$, $f^{(k)}(1)$ depends on all $f^{(j)}(1)$ for odd $j<k$.

Is there a way to see that without computing individual derivatives and successively solving for $f^{(k)}(1)$? Perhaps, combinatorially? This can be derived from the properties of the [Lah triangle](https://oeis.org/A105278), but I wonder if there is a proof that avoids those heavy computations. To see why the Lah numbers are involved, see exercise 7 on page 157-158 of [Comtet](https://archive.org/details/Comtet_Louis_-_Advanced_Coatorics/page/n83) (the case of $\alpha=-1$).

Comment: $$f( 1/z) = -f(z)$$ is equivalent to $$f \circ \mathrm{exp} \ \mathrm{is \ odd}$$ Now, call $g= f \circ \mathrm{exp}$, then $f= g \circ \ln$.

Comment: @Crostul OK, that works, thanks!